# angular-translate service is not translating for first time

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I´m using angular-translate $translate service to translate the title and meta description tags content dinamically according to the page (for SEO purposes).

I have a function that is called when a select combobox component with the language changes:

```
$scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
            $scope.langKey = langKey;
            $translate.uses(langKey);
            $rootScope.title = $translate('PAGE_TITLE');

            tmhDynamicLocale.set(langKey).then(function (){
                LocationService.setLangKey($scope.langKey);                     
                $window.moment.lang(langKey);    
            });
        };
```

All my application content is translated but the title.

My application default language is english. When I change to spanish (for first time) it´s not translating. After that, if I change to english and then to spanish again it works. All next times will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have fixed it this way:

```
$translate.uses(langKey).then(function() {
     $rootScope.title = $translate('PAGE_TITLE');
});
```

Comment: is there a reason to not use the directive?

Answer (score 0):

the translate [service](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/api/pascalprecht.translate.$translate) returns a promise

```
$translate('PAGE_TITLE').then(function(result) {
    $rootScope.title = result
});
```

Comment: I tried that but I got an undefined error in javascript.

Comment: what angular translate version are you use? edit: ah ok. dont realize that "use" returns also a promise for further use of $translate